# Command-Line Testing Using Cocoa Touch

Tags: xcode, cocoa, kif

I have developed several test for an application, and I would like to run this application using the command-line. I have read [this tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/A2-command_line_testing/A2-command_line_testing.html); however, I haven't been able to run them. When executing the following command:

```
xcodebuild test -project MyApplication.xcodeproj -scheme MyApplication -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6'
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Testing failed:
    Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
** TEST FAILED **
```

I cannot understand this error, so I wonder if I have to try a different approach or what I am doing wrong. I have to add that I am using KIF for testing.

Comment: which folder are you executing the command in?

Comment: I am executing this command from the folder where the xcodeproj is.

Comment: have you tried running using sudo?

Comment: what is the output using -v flag

Comment: also, try adding OS=latest to your destination

Comment: @D-Jones what do you think about using xctool because my tests were made using KIF?

Comment: ooo, i don't have any experience with KIF, we'll have to wait for someone else to chime in, i'm sorry!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80595/discussion-between-lmiguelvargasf-and-d-jones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking several options, I have decided to use [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) because this is a recommended tool when the tests have been done using KIF. At the beginning I had some trouble trying to run the test, but after reading other posts I have use the following commands:

For running all tests:

```
xctool/xctool.sh \
    -workspace Supermaxi.xcworkspace \
    -scheme Supermaxi \
    test  -sdk iphonesimulator
```

For running all tests in a class:

```
xctool/xctool.sh \
        -workspace Supermaxi.xcworkspace\
        -scheme Supermaxi \
        test -only FunctionalTests:TestCase000_Registration  -sdk iphonesimulator
```

For running a specific test in a class:

```
xctool/xctool.sh \
    -workspace Supermaxi.xcworkspace\
    -scheme Supermaxi \
    test -only FunctionalTests:TestCase000_Registration/test00_WrongEmail  -sdk iphonesimulator
```

All previous commands worked correctly, and this is what I wanted to do.